# Can I check react-final-form directly for whether or not it's displaying a validation error for a particular field?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-final-form

We currently have rules encoded in json that determine if react-final-form will display a validation error or not which I believe is standard. So meta.error will have data for an invalid field and our error display component will display the error. It would be convenient to be able to query something directly to find out if an error message is being displayed for a particular field. Like if the field is called name then form.name.meta.error or state.name.meta.error. Is there anything like that in the api?

Comment: Hi Alex: welcome to Stack Overflow, your question is a little unclear; can you please provide some code snippets to show what you have tried so far and to clarify what trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want a super simple way to ascertain if an error message is being displayed by react final form. Apparently there is none. I'm working on code that reads the dom to do that now. This question can be closed.